# Regular expression to match word followed by a pair of brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which is:

```py
str2s = 'orange,juices,apple,apple[-2]'
```

I'm trying to extract all those words as long as the bracket out, using regex, not to use str.split(), so I want:

```py
'orange', 'juices', 'apple', 'apple[-2]'
```

I tried using:

```py
re.findall(
    '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_%\\.]{0,}\[?[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\]?',
    str2s,
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)
```

But it only returned:

```py
'orange', 'juices', 'apple', 'apple['
```

How to get the `-2]` as well?

Comment: If your desired output is `['orange', 'juices', 'apple', 'apple[-2]']`, use `str2s.split(',')`.

Comment: i forgot to mention, the str2s supposed to be a long char, so i just used a list here, they may not have ',' in between to separate them.

Comment: Then, you should edit your question and clearly mention your problem.

Comment: @mojop You can edit the expected input and expected output into the question, and also indicate what needs to be paid attention to in the expected input, which can help everyone understand your needs faster

Comment: yep. i should have made that clear in the first place. thanks for reminding, i revised it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with match with a char a-zA-Z, then match optional word characters, and optionally match from an opening till closing square bracket.

```
\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\[[^][]*\])?
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[A-Z]\w*` Match a char a-zA-Z followed by optional word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[[^][]*\]` Match  `[...]` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UON4jn/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mOw7tH).

```
import re

str2s = 'orange,juices,apple,apple[-2]'
print(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\w*(?:\[[^][]*\])?', str2s, flags=re.I))
```

Output

```
['orange', 'juices', 'apple', 'apple[-2]']
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to split an string to a list I think you have to know the exact separator, or being able to identify those separators, being it `,` or `[,.]` or others.

If you can't define separators from items, I think it will be very hard to achieve your goal via common methods.

With that being said, in your case of `orange,juices,apple,apple[-2]`, you may use `r'([\w\[\]\-]+)'`
https://regex101.com/r/2Xj7AR/1

Answer (score 0):

The following code will extract the words the way you want:

```py
import re

words = re.compile(r'\w+\[?-?\d*\]?', re.IGNORECASE)
s = 'orange,juices,apple,apple[-2],pineapple[20]'

words.findall(s)
```

Which will result in the following:

```py
['orange', 'juices', 'apple', 'apple[-2]', 'pineapple[20]']
```

Bear in mind that the snippet above was written with the example string you provided as the base. If you need to match other types of words (`007%abc`, for example), you will need to adjust the regular expression to match more characters.